Decomposing Persian maqam into their component tetra/penta-chords
I'm trying to identify the individual tetrachords and pentachords which the various modes are built out of in Persian traditional music, but I am having trouble finding information on it. It seems the information is maybe in the Kitab al-Adwār, but I can't find any English translations.
If we take Homayoun as an example:
G Ap B C D Eb/Ep F G Ab
Maybe the gushes can be used to hint at the chord divisions:
(Ep F G)  (G Ap B C) (B C D Eb F) (F G Ab)
It would make sense that G Ap B C is one tetrachord, spanning a perfect 4th (as in the Greek system). B C D Eb F doesn't seem to fit as a pentachord though because it overlaps the first tetrachord at B instead of C, and the other two gushes are only 3 notes, and anyway if you were to take Ep F G A as a tetrachord it would be a diminished 4th and not a perfect 4th and leave roughly a ditone between the lower and upper tetrachords, which I suppose is unusual (at least for the Greek system).
I don't know what techniques could be used for deriving the individual tetrachords in the systems, aside from generating all possible 4 and 5 note subsets from the 8-9 note sets and filtering out intervals which don't add up to a perfect 4th. However it is unclear to me if their systems require that tetrachords are a perfect 4th, or what interval the pentachords are supposed to be.
Does anyone know any good resources, or know what rules are used to combine tetrachords while building these Persian systems?

It's not clear what your question is. Are you asking for a resource? A technique? A decomposition of the specific example? ...?

Are you sure it is possible? Why don't you allow shorter or longer chords as components?

@Emil shorter or longer chords may be allowed in their system, but from what I've seen so far the modes are just built from tetrachords and pentachords. The more widely disseminated ancient Greek systems were based on just the tetrachord AFAIK. Persian music theory was influenced by the Greek systems at one point, but I don't know to what extent it was so back then, and how much of that survives in to contemporary practice.

@Jean-Baptiste I know from a book I read on maqams (the one on maqamworld) that the modulation points between jins is not always the last note. Maybe dastgah has something similar. Really hard to find anything on it so don't know it.
